# Parse a table from wikipedia that is hidden

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'am pretty new here.
I want to parse a table from wikipedia from a following link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIUI

I was able to parse first table, but I can't figure out how to get the information from the second table there, the information that contains "version history" of MIUI browser.
Is there a way to parse it into a datafram? to get the version of browser in one column and Date of Release in the second column?

Thank you!

so far I have tried this, but it doesn't return anything:
Can't get the tabl's information.

```py
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIUI'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', class_='wikitable sortable mw-collapsible mw-no-collapsible jquery-tablesorter mw-made-collapsible')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Table is not hidden, but missing some dynamic class names, so you have to select more specififc based on in response available data.*

---

You could read the table directly via [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) picking it by index:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIUI',displayed_only=False)[2]
```

or matching content `match='Version'`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIUI',displayed_only=False, match='Version')[0]
```

Comment: WOW Thank you!
never knew you could do that! :))